# How does t-SNE slow down with increasing number of dimensions?

Tags: data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, tsne, scalability

I'm trying to understand the computational bounds of t-SNE.  It's learned with SGD, so it'll have to go through some number of gradient-descent iterations.  We can ignore that here, and focus on the time for each iteration.  Barnes-Hut changes it from $O(N^2)$ to $O(N log(N))$ on each iteration, with $N$ data points.  But how does it scale with $M$ dimensions?

It would have to be at least $O(N log(N) M)$.  But is there an $M^2$ component anywhere?